# Removing the outer-most border of the table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I am new to iPhone development. I want to know , is it possible to remove the outer border of the table view, but I don't want to remove the line that separates the table view cells. If I set the tableview separator property to none it removes the outer border of the tableview and also line separating the cells. I want only the outer border to be removed without removing the cell separator. Is there any way?

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 1):

You must set a header and/or footer view to remove those nasty lines up top and bottom but keep the cell separators.

I do it like this:

```
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.myTableView setTableHeaderView:v];
[self.myTableView setTableFooterView:v];
[v release];
```

Comment: hi,I achieved my task by setting the table view background color to transparent and then the separator color to black.

Comment: OK so perhaps I didn't understand your question enough. This method I posted will remove the lines above and below your cells in your tableview yet keep the separator lines in tact.

Answer (score 0):

Give separator property to none. It will remove the border completely.

Now, inherit a tableViewCell and override drwaRect method. here write a logic to draw a line at the bottom of the cell.